# Why I'm getting blank white screen instead of an equivalent array of JSON object after executing json_decode() in following case?

Tags: php, arrays, json, request

Following is my code :

```
$json_body = $application->request->getBody();
```

if I `echo $json_body;` then I get following output :

```
{
    photo =     (
                {
            fileURL = "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/UYUkZVHERGufB0enRbJo";
            filename = "IMG_0004.JPG";
        },
                {
            fileURL = "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WZeQAR4zRJaPyW6hDcza";
            filename = "IMG_0003.JPG";
        }
    );
    "status_info" = "";
}
```

Then I execute following code :

```
$request_data = json_decode($json_body, true);
```

Now if I `echo $request_data;` I'm getting blank white screen. Why so?

Why I'm not getting equivalent array of JSON object? Please help me.

Or if I'm sending the invalid JSON data please correct the data so that it would be in proper JSON format.

Comment: Try `var_dump($request_data)` and let us know if you see an output with that?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea: I tried var_dump($request_data); then I got NULL as a output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON should be:

```
{
    "photo": [
        {
            "fileURL": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/UYUkZVHERGufB0enRbJo",
            "filename": "IMG_0004.JPG"
        },
        {
            "fileURL": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WZeQAR4zRJaPyW6hDcza",
            "filename": "IMG_0003.JPG"
        }
    ],
    "status_info": ""
}
```

var_dump the result from your json_decode with the above json will show you ther resulting array:

```
array(2) {
  ["photo"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["fileURL"]=>
      string(55) "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/UYUkZVHERGufB0enRbJo"
      ["filename"]=>
      string(12) "IMG_0004.JPG"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["fileURL"]=>
      string(55) "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/WZeQAR4zRJaPyW6hDcza"
      ["filename"]=>
      string(12) "IMG_0003.JPG"
    }
  }
  ["status_info"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#tPPmwlRuo).

Answer (score 1):

Two things, firstly: $json_body is not valid json format, 
secondly: json_decode will return an array, which you should then print_r or var_dump out.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `$json_body` isn't encoded at all.

If you do `var_dump($json_body)` you should get - if it is json_encoded -

```
string(228) "{"1":{"fileURL":"https:\/\/www.filepicker.io\/api\/file\/UYUkZVHERGufB0enRbJo","filename":"IMG_0004.JPG"},"2":{"fileURL":"https:\/\/www.filepicker.io\/api\/file\/WZeQAR4zRJaPyW6hDcza","filename":"IMG_0003.JPG"},"status_info":""}"
```

not an array.